# How to adjust for jumps in a timeseries?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

```
df <- structure(list(
        asset = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "X", "y", "y", "y", "y"), 
        datetime = c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-04", 
                     "2010-01-05", "2010-01-06", "2010-02-02", "2010-02-03", 
                     "2010-02-04", "2010-02-05"), 
        price = c(10, 11, 12, 400, 450, 430, 5, 6, 4, 220), 
        returns = c(NA, 0.1, 0.09, 32.33, 0.12, -0.04, NA, 0.2, -0.33, 54)), 
        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L)
     )
```

Hi I have this df for which I have a problem in the price column, as you can see at a random moment in time the price can explode and I get a jump.

I coded the jump as being the `return > 1`, now I want to correct those jump, hence every time i get a `return > 1`, R must convert the new price from row[i] to all the next ones.
It must be that in `row[i]` the price is reported equal to the price in `row[i-1]`, for the others the return must be considered, hence for `row[i+1]` the new price should be `price[i]*(1+return[i+1])`

I have no idea on how to do it since it definitely goes far beyond my R abilities.

Comment: The lengths of your data.frame implies differing number of rows

Comment: Can you show your desired output? Not sure I understand.

Comment: for the col "price" i need it to become == `c(10, 11, 12, 12, 13.44, 12.90, 5, 6, 4, 4)`  Where the new prices are computed by: 
- the first, it was 400, is now equal to the lag(price) == 12, then the other are just `lag(price)*(1+returns)` where `lag(price)` is the newly computed price, hence the 12 instead of 400, then `12*1,12` then `13.44*0.96` etc etc

Comment: it would be perfect if, after the computation, R also check if now the returns are coherent, hence < 1. The idea is to apply something like I wrote iff the returns > 1 hence after the computations, hence with the new prices, R should compute again the returns  `(price-lag(price)/lag(price)` and check again if lower than 1. Iff greater than one should redo the computations

Comment: It could be for example that the price for x can be something like `c(10, 11, 12, 400, 450, 430, 400, 380, 5000, 5523) hence in this case the correction must be applied twice!

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to make a new group each time the price of an asset more than doubles from its prior row. Then we can calculate the returns within each group within each asset:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(asset) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(coalesce(price / lag(price) > 2, 0))) %>%
  group_by(asset, grp) %>%
  mutate(returns2 = price / lag(price) - 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   asset datetime   price returns   grp returns2
   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 x     2010-01-01    10   NA        0  NA     
 2 x     2010-01-02    11    0.1      0   0.100 
 3 x     2010-01-03    12    0.09     0   0.0909
 4 x     2010-01-04   400   32.3      1  NA     
 5 x     2010-01-05   450    0.12     1   0.125 
 6 X     2010-01-06   430   -0.04     0  NA     
 7 y     2010-02-02     5   NA        0  NA     
 8 y     2010-02-03     6    0.2      0   0.2   
 9 y     2010-02-04     4   -0.33     0  -0.333 
10 y     2010-02-05   220   54        1  NA
```

Comment: yeah, that's ok, but I need then to adjust the "price" column to avoid those jumps. For example I can bring back the line "4" price to be equal to line "3" hence to 12. And for the following days I can just add those returns to the starting price in line "4" and so on. But i'm not able to tell R to do this